How to clear form inputs in React after submission
I'm submitting data from my form to my email using emailjs service. However when i remove event.preventDefault() function in the formhandler function, no message or mail is sent to my email while the opposite happens when the event.PreventDefault() function is present.  I want all the details of the previous user on submission to be cleared after submitting the form.
example:
function myForm(){
        const [formData, setFormData] = React.useState({
         fullName: "",
        emailAddress: "",
        });
        function handleChange(){
               const {name,value} = event.target;
                setFormData((prevFormData)=>{
                    return (
                           {...prevFormData,
                              [name] : value
                            }
            )
        })
            })
}

        function handleSubmit(event){
           event.preventDefault();
           send(
                 formData
                )
      }
      return (
              <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                     <input type="text" value={formData.fullName} onChange={handleChange}/>
                     <input type="email" value={formData.emailAddress} onChange={handleChange}/>
                     <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
              </form>
              )
}

I tried creating a new variable let myNewData ={} to store the data from formData but this did not work.

In your handleSubmit function just reset the formData state:
 function handleSubmit(event){
           event.preventDefault();
           send(formData);
           setFormData({ fullName: "",emailAddress: ""})
   }


thanks for the solution.  Setting the object values back to empty string changed in the input elements.

It is better to do this after successfully sending the request, otherwise there may be issues on mobile devices.
